# paste(x, collapse ", ") causing an error within lapply function in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have spit the `mtcars` data into a list, with an evement for every `cyl`.

```
> splitCars <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

Now I want to create a summary of year element of the list. It should contain two elements:

1. `Ngears` - number of unique gears
2. `gears` - a character string of all possible gears

to create the character string i am using the following:

```
> cat(paste(shQuote(levels(as.factor(splitCars$`8`$gear)), type="cmd"), collapse=", "))
"3", "5">
```

Which runs fine here, for just one element of the list. Now i want to use the `lapply` to summarize all alements within `splitCars`

```
> splitCars <- lapply(splitCars, function(x){
+   x %>% summarize(Ngears = length(unique(gear)),
+                   gears = cat(paste(shQuote(levels(as.factor(gear)), type="cmd"), collapse=", ")))
+ })
```

But i get an error. Why is this causing an error within the `lapply` function?

```
"3", "4", "5"
 Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `gears`.
x Input `gears` must be a vector, not NULL.
ℹ Input `gears` is `cat(paste(shQuote(levels(as.factor(gear)), type = "cmd"), collapse = ", "))`.
```

when looking into the `show trace` option in R the last couple of information is:

```
24.
stop(fallback) 
23.
signal_abort(cnd) 
22.
abort(bullets, class = "dplyr_error") 
21.
(function (e) 
{
    local_call_step(dots = dots, .index = i, .fn = "summarise", 
        .dot_data = inherits(e, "rlang_error_data_pronoun_not_found")) ... 
20.
signalCondition(cnd) 
19.
signal_abort(cnd) 
18.
(function (message = NULL, class = NULL, ..., trace = NULL, parent = NULL, 
    .subclass) 
{
    validate_signal_args(.subclass) ... 
17.
exec(abort, class = class, !!!.envir) 
16.
abort_glue(character(0), list(result = NULL), "dplyr:::summarise_unsupported_type") 
15.
mask$eval_all_summarise(quo) 
14.
withCallingHandlers({
    for (i in seq_along(dots)) {
        quo <- dots[[i]]
        chunks[[i]] <- mask$eval_all_summarise(quo) ... 
13.
summarise_cols(.data, ...) 
12.
summarise.data.frame(., Ngears = length(unique(gear)), gears = cat(paste(shQuote(levels(as.factor(gear)), 
    type = "cmd"), collapse = ", ")))
```

**how can this be fixed? or is there a better way to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach building values individually:

```
#Code for list
splitCars <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
#my fun
myfun <- function(x)
{
  #Ngears
  v1 <- length(unique(x$gear))
  v2 <- paste0(unique(levels(as.factor(x$gear))),collapse = ', ')
  #Build data
  y <- data.frame(Ngears=v1,gears=v2,stringsAsFactors = F)
  return(y)
}
#Apply
splitCars <- lapply(splitCars,myfun)
```

Output:

```
splitCars
$`4`
  Ngears   gears
1      3 3, 4, 5

$`6`
  Ngears   gears
1      3 3, 4, 5

$`8`
  Ngears gears
1      2  3, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat` doesn't have a `return` value as it is just for `print`ing to the console.  So, we can remove the `cat`.  With `tidyverse`, the `length(unique` can be `n_distinct`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(splitCars, ~ .x %>%
                 summarize(Ngears = n_distinct(gear),
                 gears = toString(shQuote(levels(as.factor(gear)),
             type="cmd"))))
```

-output

```
#$`4`
#  Ngears         gears
#1      3 "3", "4", "5"

#$`6`
#  Ngears         gears
#1      3 "3", "4", "5"

#$`8`
#  Ngears    gears
#1      2 "3", "5"
```

---

Also, there is no need to split, as it can be done with group by operation

```
 mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarize(Ngears = n_distinct(gear),
              gears = toString(shQuote(levels(as.factor(gear)),
             type="cmd")), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl Ngears gears                
#  <dbl>  <int> <chr>                
#1     4      3 "\"3\", \"4\", \"5\""
#2     6      3 "\"3\", \"4\", \"5\""
#3     8      2 "\"3\", \"5\""
```